# Как разбить класс на несколько файлов как в C#?

Tags: ооп, typescript, visual-studio-code

Как можно разбить класс на несколько файлов? Чтобы часть методов класса была в одном файле и часть в другом?

Файл entity.ts

```
/// <reference path="settings.ts" />

namespace Game{
    export class Entity{
        private _size: Object;
        private _pos: Object;
        
        public name: string;

        constructor(name: string, x: number, y: number){
            this._size = {width: 15, height: 15};
            this._pos = {x: x, y: y};

            this.name = name;
        }

        public get pos(){
            return this._pos;
        }
    } 
}
```

Файл settings.ts

```
/// <reference path="entity.ts" />

namespace Game{
    export class Entity{
        settings(){
            return 'Settings for ' + this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: никак, в typescript нет partial классов как в c#

Comment: @Grundy печально

Comment: Хотя, [на самом деле можно](https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/how-to-extend-an-existing-typescript-class-ef2bfe4b6690#6027), но не совсем тот подход что в C#

Answer (score 0):

Grundy уже написал :)

Да, разбить класс на несколько файлов можно, но без насущеной необходимости лучше этого конечно не делать.

Тенология называется typescript augmentation
[документация](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Вот прекрасная статья на эту тему: [статья](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/typescript-module-augmentation)

Если кратко - то во втором файле пишите

```
declare module "./pet" {
  interface Pet {
    age: number;
    walk(location: string);
  }

  Pet.prototype.walk = (location:string) => `Likes to walk in the ${location}`
}
```

Как видите - смотрится не очень и лучше без необходимости так не делать.

Но! данные метод весьма полезен когда Вы используете некую библиотеку и Вам надо расширить ее функциональность.

P.S. такой синтаксис сейчас считается устаревшим и лучше его не использовать

```
/// <reference path="settings.ts" />
```

Comment: Мне нужен такой метод для вложенного класса. А насчёт устаревшего синтаксиса - есть ли равные альтернативы, работающие так же?

Comment: Прямо в документации ссылку не нашел - но eslint пишет что лучше использовать импорт
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/triple-slash-reference/

>>вложенный класс мне ни разу не приходилось использовать. Вложенные функции конечно были, но вот вложенный класс мне ни разу не встречался в коде.

Возможно Вам надо переписать код как то иначе